# FileDialouge Filter type not accepting .tiproj

Tags: wpf, filter, openfiledialog

I am trying to filter the file type in the openfiledialouge but it is not accepting .tiproj it saying invalid file type.

```
 Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

                  dlg.DefaultExt = ".tiproj";
                  dlg.Filter = "*.tiproj";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below format worked for me.

```
 Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
 dlg.Filter = "tiproj files (*.tiproj)|*.tiproj";
```